# How to cc a maillist in mailx command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, quoting

I had prepared a cc maillist as below:

```
/appl/tracker/TEST> more abc.maillist
xyz@yahoo.com, a123@gmail.com, abc@xyz.com
```

And a to maillist as below:

```
/appl/tracker/TEST> more Servicedesk.maillist
123@gmail.com
```

My script is `ab.sh` which will call the `mailx` command and send an email. This should send email to `cc_list` keeping the id's in cc and `to_list` placing the id provided in the list in to list.

```
/appl/tracker/TEST> more ab.sh
#!/bin/ksh
l_date=`date +%d%m%y`
CC_LIST=`cat /appl/tracker/TEST/abc.maillist`
TO_LIST=`cat /appl/tracker/TEST/Servicedesk.maillist`
MY_Q="'"

cc_list="$MY_Q$CC_LIST$MY_Q"

echo $cc_list

BODYFILE='Please find attached file having my details.Test mail'

echo $CC_LIST
echo $TO_LIST

mailx -s 'HI'  -c $cc_list $TO_LIST <<-EOF
`echo $BODYFILE`
EOF

/appl/tracker/TEST>
```

Output:

There is an error being occured stating that there is an unbalanced `"`.
Can anyone please help me getting the solution for this.

Comment: The echo in backticks in a here document is a horribly complex and convoluted way of passing a variable to a script.

Answer (score 4):

I don't get that error message.  Are you sure you have pasted everything correctly?
Anyway, an immediate problem is that you need to quote any variable interpolations.  It's not clear why you need variables for this at all, besides.  Here is a much simplified refactoring of your script.

```
#!/bin/sh

CC_LIST=`cat /appl/tracker/TEST/abc.maillist`
TO_LIST=`cat /appl/tracker/TEST/Servicedesk.maillist`

BODYFILE='Please find attached file having my details. Test mail'

echo "$CC_LIST"
echo "$TO_LIST"

echo "$BODYFILE" | mailx -s 'HI' -c "$CC_LIST" "$TO_LIST"
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables must be double quoted to avoid expanding as list:

```
mailx -s 'HI'  -c "$cc_list" "$TO_LIST" <<-EOF
$BODYFILE
EOF
```